# Agudath Israel Convention

Tags: history, internet, organizations, speeches-addresses

Where can I find information on the annual Agudath Israel (of America?) convention that happens around Thanksgiving time?

I have been hearing references to this convention since I was young, but have never been aware of the details. By searching online, I can find some articles reporting on speeches made there, and personalities who have made appearances, but not a lot in the way of rigor.

Is there an archive (online or in print) of past proceedings?

Can information be obtained online about the upcoming one?

Comment: Back when Agudath Israel had its official publication, the Jewish Observer, I assume the information would be there. Now that it's no longer in print ... I don't know, maybe something like Mishpacha would report on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agudath Israel of America has an annual convention Thanksgiving weekend. It has big-name rabbis and a good number of other speakers, loosely (and sometimes not so loosely) on one theme. The main speeches are Thursday night and Saturday night; a number of people go only for one or both of those nights. It serves also as an official membership meeting for whatever purposes they need that for (electing officers, or whatever). It takes place somewhere in the general vicinity of New York City (i.e., within driving distance). Audiorecordings of all non-*Shabas* events are available soon after each year's convention from AIA (I think from its Reshet Shiurei Torah / Torah Projects Commission): +1-212-797-9000. There's also content on http://yourconvention.org.

Their annual dinner is in the spring, I think. They also have regional conventions, including, I *think*, at least a Midwest, a Florida, and a West Coast (or California?).

If they still have an organ, it will doubtless have photos and a summary of the convention afterward. But the *JO*, I learned from [Shalom's comment, above](/questions/3374/agudath-israel-convention/3389#comment66606_3374), is no longer being published, and *Coalition* isn't either AFAIK. Is *Dos Yiddishe Vort*? or *Inside Track*? If not, doubtless *Hamodia* will cover the convention.

As for an archive of past conventions, doubtless AIA keeps it, perhaps in its Orthodox Jewish Archives (I think it's called).

Comment: Just a note: In 2012, the convention was Christmastime rather than Thanksgiving weekend, because of the aftermath of [Sandy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Sandy_(2012)).

Answer (score 1):

Some information about the upcoming convention is here: https://www.5tjt.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5580:87th-national-agudah-convention-to-grapple-with-%22formidable-challenges%22-november-26-29

Comment: WARNING: When visiting the above link, I got this message: Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer! The website at www.5tjt.com contains elements from the site poltinvas.com, which appears to host malware – software that can hurt your computer or otherwise operate without your consent. Just visiting a site that contains malware can infect your computer.

Comment: Also, that article is talking about the 87th Convention. This year's Convention is the 88th. I am also looking for information. If I find any, I will post it IY"H

Comment: Funny, I remember specifically checking to see if the date was right.  As far as malware, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The Official position of the Agudas Yisroel is not to have Internet site hence you will not find the information online. Secondly there is one CONVENTION in the Midwest versus the New York one first I suggest you decide which ou want to attend then for general information about the Agudah see here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agudath_Israel_of_America
and for more INFO about the conventions I suggest you get in contact by phone or mail to
Agudath Israel of America
42 Broadway # 14, New York, NY 10004-3889
(212) 797-9000 ‎