# Getaways that are focused on learning

Tags: torah-study, product-recommendation, travel, adult-learning

What available programs are there for someone looking to get away for a few days in an environment focused on learning?

I know of many such programs targeted for Ba'alei Teshuva or potential Ba'alei Teshuva, but I'm looking for something more designed for someone who is already committed to learning and proficient in learning Gemara with Rishonim, but looking to make a vacation out of an environment with minimal distractions for a few days to recharge.

Something in the New York area is preferred, but any information is helpful, as they will know of other similar programs.

Comment: Something for couples, too, would be good.

Comment: Are you looking for a yeshiva that allows you to stay and learn for a few days, or are you looking for a trip through the forest, that is isolated from other people?

Comment: @avi, a yeshiva environment is fine, but to fit what I had in mind it would have to be bein-hazmanim, or otherwise a bit of a different schedule than just sitting in zal with full-timers. Otherwise, (in NY anyway) there is always a kollel.

Comment: @Yishai I was trying to give two extremes so you could better explain what you are looking for.  What are you looking for that isn't a Kollel?

Comment: Limmud?  (I've never been, but I've heard good things about it.)

Comment: @avi, in a kollel the flow and wavelength that everyone is on is very different, as they have a longer term plan, and an individual is just an add-on. I was looking for something with more of a program and agenda.

Comment: @Yishai so a 2 day kollel would be a valid answer? How about the walk in the forest?

Comment: @avi, yes a 2 day kollel where everyone involved was more or less there for that two days would be a valid answer. I'm not seeing how a lot of learning happens in a walk in the forest, though.

Comment: @Yishai, you asked or an 'environment focused on learning', and also said you wanted to 'recharge' and have a 'vacation'.  I can focus on learning while alone in the woods and be relaxed :)  So I wasn't 100% sure what you were asking for.

Comment: @avi, I'm sure, but I was looking for something that is more of an established program, and not a do it yourself thing.

Answer (score 2):

Agudath Israel of America has an annual convention Thanksgiving weekend. It has big-name rabbis and a good number of other speakers, loosely (and sometimes not so loosely) on one theme; while the theme is never 'pure' Torah study, it is always Torah-based, and the speeches include Torah thoughts. The main speeches are Thursday night and Saturday night; a number of people go only for one or both of those nights. There are also *shiurim*, 'pure' Torah classes. It takes place somewhere in the general vicinity of New York City (i.e., within driving distance). Audiorecordings of all non-*Shabas* events are available soon after each year's convention from AIA (I think from its Reshet Shiurei Torah / Torah Projects Commission): +1-212-797-9000. There's also content on http://yourconvention.org.

Comment: [More info.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3389)