# Seeking Jewish vacation website

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, travel

Seeking websites that list and describe (and hopefully rate) vacation locations with a Jewish orientation (e.g., indicating the availability of a minyan daily, or on Shabbat).  (If this question is not appropriate for MY, where might I find this information?)

Comment: I don't know if this is on topic.

Comment: @mevaqesh Modified question to address your comment. I think MY needs a subject area for such general questions that do not fit in the existing categories.

Comment: Those questions which are topic can be raised on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam) I doubt people would object.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34154/getaways-that-are-focused-on-learning